# Scraping HTML table with Nokogiri and saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, web-scraping, nokogiri

I've been trying to scrape a website for education information to save to my app database. The site has a three column table as follows:

```
<thead>
<tr height="20">
<th height="20" scope="col" width="91">UKPRN</th>
<th scope="col" width="87">INSTID</th>
<th scope="col" width="264">Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10000291</td>
<td>0047</td>
<td>Anglia Ruskin University</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10007759</td>
<td>0108</td>
<td>Aston University</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10000571</td>
<td>0048</td>
<td>Bath Spa University</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10007850</td>
<td>0109</td>
<td>The University of Bath</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10007152</td>
<td>0026</td>
<td>University of Bedfordshire</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10007760</td>
<td>0127</td>
<td>Birkbeck College</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10007140</td>
<td>0052</td>
<td>Birmingham City University</td>
</tr>
<tr height="20">
<td height="20">10006840</td>
<td>0110</td>
<td>The University of Birmingham</td>
</tr>
```

and so on. I want to get the 8 figure reference, the 4 figure reference and the school name saved to my database under UKPRN, instid and name respectively.

This is the only table on the page so is easy to grab. So far my code in irb looks like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
rows = data.css("tr")
rows.each do |row|
   name = row.css("td")[2]
   ukprn = row.css("td")[0]
   instid = row.css("td")[1]
end
```

This seems to work ok as when I print one of the variables it seems to pick up the right data, but I can't get rid of the  tags around the text, and once done, I'm not sure how I would go about saving this data to my `institute` model in the database. The attributes should correlate with the names given above. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
rows = html.css("tbody tr")
rows.each do |row|
   ukprn, instid, name = row.css('td').map(&:content)
   Institute.create!(ukprn: ukprn, instid: instid, name: name) 
end
```

I took just the `tr`s in the `tbody`

Comment: I'm getting `uninitialized constant Institute`. Is there some way to connect the irb to the application that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't use irb but rails console

Comment: D'oh! It's been a while since I used Rails! Works a treat. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content
```

Is supposed to give you only what is inside your selected block

Try `name = row.css("td")[2].content`

Comment: I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass` whereas without `.content` on the end it still seems to work.

Comment: meaning you have some 'row.css("td")[2]' set to a nil value. check the awnser above, seems solid